# Nest: Indexing a PDF, recieving Status Code 400, "No Content Provided"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to index and search a PDF based off what I learned here:
[ElasticSearch & attachment type (NEST C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781946/elasticsearch-attachment-type-nest-c)

But am getting a "Status Code 400, No Content Provided" error.  The pdf is about 7KB in size, about as small as I could make one, just has some text in it.

Suggestions?  Code and output below.  Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nest;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace SearchPDFConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // create es client
            string index = "pdftestitems";

            Console.WriteLine("client stuff...");

            var node = new Uri("http://tns-dev.pts-eden.org:9200");
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node).SetDefaultIndex(index);
            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            Console.WriteLine("deleting index...");

            // delete index if any
            var di = client.DeleteIndex(index);

            Console.WriteLine(di.ConnectionStatus.HttpStatusCode);

            Console.WriteLine("creating index...");

            // Create your index explicitly before you index any instances of your class. If you don't do this, it will use dynamic mapping and ignore your attribute mapping. If you change your mapping in the future, always recreate the index.
            var ci = client.CreateIndex(index, c => c.AddMapping<Document>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));

            Console.WriteLine(di.ConnectionStatus.HttpStatusCode);

            string path = "test2.pdf";

            var attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Content = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
            attachment.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            attachment.Name = "test2.pdf";

            var doc = new Document()
            {
                ID = 2,
                Title = "test2",
                Content = "This is a test."
            };
            var doc2 = new Document()
            {
                ID = 1,
                Title = "test",
                Content = "good luck",
                File = attachment
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Indexing document 1...");

            var status = client.Index<Document>(doc);

            Console.WriteLine(status.ConnectionStatus);

            Console.WriteLine("Indexing document 2...");

            var status2 = client.Index<Document>(doc2);

            Console.WriteLine(status2.ConnectionStatus);

            Console.WriteLine("sleeping 1s...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            string stringsearch = "test";

            //var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Type("document").Query(qs => qs.QueryString(q => q.Query(stringsearch))));
            var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(qs => qs.QueryString(q => q.Query(stringsearch))));

            Console.WriteLine(searchResults.Documents.Count());

            foreach (var sd in searchResults.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sd.Title);
            }

        }
    }

    [ElasticType(Name = "document")]
    public class Document
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Store = true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Store = true)]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Attachment, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets, Store = true)]
        public Attachment File { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attachment
    {
        [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content_type")]
        public string ContentType { get; set; }

        [ElasticProperty(Name = "_name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output of my program:

```
C:\PROGRAMMING\SearchPDFTest\SearchPDFConsole\bin\Debug>SearchPDFConsole.exe
client stuff...
deleting index...
200
creating index...
200
Indexing document 1...
StatusCode: 201,
        Method: PUT,
        Url: http://tns-dev.pts-eden.org:9200/pdftestitems/document/2,
        Request: {
  "iD": 2,
  "title": "test2",
  "content": "This is a test."
},
        Response: <Response stream not captured or already read to completion by
 serializer, set ExposeRawResponse() on connectionsettings to force it to be set
 on>
Indexing document 2...
StatusCode: 400,
        Method: PUT,
        Url: http://tns-dev.pts-eden.org:9200/pdftestitems/document/1,
        Request: {
  "iD": 1,
  "title": "test",
  "content": "good luck",
  "file": {
    "_content": "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjE5IDAgb2JqDTw8L0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZS9
GaXJzdCA5L0xlbmd0aCAxMzkvTiAyL1R5cGUvT2JqU3RtPj5zdHJlYW0NCmjeTM3BCsIwDAbgV/mfwLQ
brQijB3cUYQxvY4figuzSjrYDfXvbenCH/JCEL2khoKAVuo56v7sESbd1iZPKi3GmOy+rvfr3JE4CpbR
scp4vOWd6fDamwb44GlMPuMQuRcimaOqD36pFdUUdLx6ngw1Zoq1u5Oj38OQI/et9sokh/v+M+QowAEh
[LOTS MORE BASE64 ENCODED STUFF]
mL1dbMSAyIDFdPj5zdHJlYW0NCmjeYmIAAiZGpmUMTAwMPkDWP0UGpv/8a4Gsj8GMQDHG/yACxGIAsRi
YIaz/Aun/gKwaoDamDJDeqSBWIZBgfAoiZoAIRyDx8g1I9iWIuwpISGkyAAQYAArYEhcNCmVuZHN0cmV
hbQ1lbmRvYmoNc3RhcnR4cmVmDQo3MTE2DQolJUVPRg0K",
    "_content_type": "application/pdf",
    "_name": "test2.pdf"
  }
},
        Response: <Response stream not captured or already read to completion by
 serializer, set ExposeRawResponse() on connectionsettings to force it to be set
 on>
        ExceptionMessage: No content is provided.
         StackTrace:
sleeping 1s...
1
test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with a simple PDF created in Word, and it seems to work fine for me.

I'm running ES 1.4.4 with elasticsearch-mapper-attachments 2.4.3.
Both index operations return proper 2xx status code, and I'm able to search for the PDF afterwards.

Can you make sure that your PDF is proper? Try creating a new one from another program maybe?

Comment: I was running against an older ES and mapper attachment.  If I renamed _content to just "content" it worked in the attachment class .. i've since run into various issues around the mapping decorators not working: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1276 .  Anyway, i've got most everything at this point, thank you.