# Elasticsearch Nest: Indexing Attachment Type

Tags: mapping, attachment, nest, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I am trying to to index a pdf document with elasticsearch/NEST. I am very new at this, and the question might be confusing. I tried every solution I could find and nothing worked.

This is my model:

```
public class Lecture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "document", Type = FieldType.Attachment, TermVector = TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets, Store = true)]
    public Attachment Document { get; set; }
    //public string Document { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is creation of an instance of that model from the data I retrieved from database:

```
Type t = data.GetType();
        if (t.Name.Contains("Lecture"))
        {
            PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Document");
            object propDocument = p.GetValue(data, null);
            p = t.GetProperty("PostDate");
            object propPostDate = p.GetValue(data, null);
            p = t.GetProperty("Title");
            object propTitle = p.GetValue(data, null);
            p = t.GetProperty("CourseId");
            object propCourseId = p.GetValue(data, null);
            p = t.GetProperty("Filepath");
            object propFilepath = p.GetValue(data, null);
            Lecture lecture = new Lecture();
            lecture.Id = id;
            lecture.CourseId = Int32.Parse(propCourseId.ToString());
            lecture.Title = propTitle.ToString();
            lecture.PostDate = DateTime.Parse(propPostDate.ToString());
            lecture.Filepath = propFilepath.ToString();
            //lecture.Document = Convert.ToBase64String(ObjectToByteArray(propDocument));
            lecture.Document = new Attachment();
            lecture.Document.Content= Convert.ToBase64String(ObjectToByteArray(propDocument));
            lecture.Document.ContentType = "aplication/pdf";
            lecture.Document.Name = propFilepath.ToString();
```

Then I index it:

```
var result = this.client.Index<Lecture>(lecture, i => i.Index(indexName.ToLower())
                    .Id(id));
```

In the index metadata info, I have the document mapping, with all three properties, but there is no specified type of the document. I suppose it should be the "attachment", but maybe I'm wrong. The problem is that I can't search through the pdf file, elasticsearch only sees base64 encoded string value, and it doesn't interpret it as text. I installed mapper-attachments plugin 2.6.0 and I have elasticsearch 1.6.0. Please any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781946/elasticsearch-attachment-type-nest-c

Comment: can u send the mapping created in the index ?
run something like 
10.0.200.11:9200/{indexName}/{type}/_mapping?pretty