# Indexing pdf files in Elasticsearch 2 with Nest 2

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, mono, nest

I want to index PDF files into Elasticsearch as an attachment and then query over its content. So far I try to index the document but the file is not been attached to it or at least elastichq is not able to show it and the elasticsearch is printing an error.

This is the indexing:

```
var attachment = new Attachment ();
string path = "bankvsmartin.pdf";
attachment.Name = path;
attachment.Content = Convert.ToBase64String (File.ReadAllBytes(path));
attachment.ContentType = "application/pdf";
cases.Add( new Case{
    Author="Martin Luther 2",
    CaseName="Bank vs Martin",
    File= attachment
});
var indexName = "indexname";
client.Map<Case>(m => m.UpdateAllTypes());
foreach (var caze in cases)
{
    var rsp = client.Index (caze, i=>i.Index(indexName).Type("cases"));
}
```

And the classes and mapping definitions:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "cases")]
public class Case
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    [Attachment(Store = true)]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }

    public Case ()
    {

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Case: " + Author + " - " + File.Name;
    }
}


public class Attachment
{
    [String(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Elasticsearch error in console when trying to retrieve the attachment:

```
emoteTransportException[[Sin-Eater][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read

/search[phase/fetch/id]]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[field [file] isn't a leaf field];
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field [file] isn't a leaf field
    at org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.FetchPhase.execute(FetchPhase.java:138)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:590)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$FetchByIdTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$FetchByIdTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:405)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am trying to accomplish pretty much the same thing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781946/elasticsearch-attachment-type-nest-c) but with a more recent version of [Nest](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch).

Using Elasticsearch 2.2, Nest 2.0.2, Mono / .Net 4.5

### UPDATE

Here is the generated mapping

```
"mappings": {
  "cases": {
    "properties": {
      "author": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "case_name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "file": {
        "properties": {
          "_content": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "_content_type": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "_name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Comment: @Rob Ok there is the generated mapping and for some reason is not creating a proper mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mapping worked after [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1826) was fixed:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "cases")]
public class Case
{
    public Case()
    {
    }

    [String(Name = "case_name")]
    public string CaseName { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "md5")]
    public string Md5 { get; set; }

    [Attachment(Name="file")]
    public Attachment File { get; set; }

}


public class Attachment
{
    public Attachment()
    {

    }

    [String(Name = "_author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_lenght")]
    public long ContentLength { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content_type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [Date(Name = "_date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_keywords")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [String(Name = "_content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you cannot map an attachment by using attributes. Attachment type in ES and NEST requires a complex mapping which cannot be accomplished with attribute based mapping. You can see many examples if you download NEST source code and check the unit tests.

You can specifically define your mapping using fluent API of NEST. Here is an example:

```
var mappingResponse = elasticClient.Map<Case>( m => m
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties( ps => ps
            .String( s => s
                .Name( f => f.CaseName)
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                .Store(true))
.Attachment( atm => atm
                .Name( p => p.File)
                .FileField( f => f
                        .Name( p => p.File)
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                        .Store(true)
                        .TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))
                .AuthorField( af => af
                        .Name( p => p.Author)
                        .Store(true)
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                        .TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)))));
```

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that I don't need the Attachment class I wrote to map an attachment? What type of object would be the File?

Comment: Yes. You do not need an extra class for that. You should convert the pdf byte array to base64 string and assign to a property in your Case  class. And then map that property as an attachment type using NEST. It is the same logic like mapping a Number type. Only difference is that Attachment Type has extra fields like Author, File, Content etc.

Comment: Well friend, I am trying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608490/mapping-attachment-type-manually-elasticsearch-2-and-nest2) but is giving me the Null reference exception when defining any of the attachment fields like Author, Is there anything wrong?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1864
I think it's the dictionary initalization issue given in #1826, but opened up an issue just to be sure.

Btw: I tried the above mapping on NEST 1.7 and it works.

Comment: Yep it is most likely a duplicate, and yes again I also tried the older version of Nest but I will most likely be using 2.x elasticsearch for this project so is not possible cuz of compatibility. Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: I also tried the [fix/mapping](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/compare/fix/mappings) branch and now it's working, the solution will be most likely included in next release according to [the developers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1837)